# MSVC linker cannot find entry point in object files produced by NASM

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, nasm, entry-point

I'm experimenting with some assembly programming. Here is my very simple program :

```
extern ExitProcess

segment Main

Entry:

push 0
call ExitProcess
```

For assembling I use **NASM** :

```
nasm.exe -f win64 -o Entry.obj Entry.asm
```

The code compiles successfully. I then link the single object file with the **MSVC linker** :

```
link.exe /subsystem:console /entry:Entry /out:Test.exe Entry.obj kernel32.lib
```

The code does not link and gives me this error :

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Entry
```

I can't really figure out why there's an error, because I'm pretty that I have defined the entry point. I then try **GoLink** instead :

```
GoLink.exe /console /entry Entry /fo Test.exe Entry.obj
```

The code links successfully! But why? Why does my object file work with GoLink, but not with the MSVC linker? Do I have to specify some kind of linkage to make `Entry` visible to `link.exe` ?

Comment: The first question you have to ask yourself - am I trying to build a 32-bit windows or 64-bit windows EXE? It is hard to tell from your question because you assemble with `-f win64` but the code you wrote pushes arguments on the stack (for `ExitProcess`) like it was 32-bit code (64-bit calling convention passes the first 4 parameters in registers)

Comment: To mark a label to have external linkage you'd have to do something like `global Entry`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm trying to build a 64-bit executable, but I just assumed that 32-bit code would still work and it could just prefix the instruction or enter some legacy mode (Idk, I'm not an expert). Anyways, your solution worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: If NASM didn't put the symbol in the symbol table of the `.obj` in the first place, nothing you tell the linker can make it work.  You need `global Entry` in your NASM source code.  (Without that, it is technically still in the symbol table, but only as a private symbol, normally for debugging.  Or GoLink might have defaulted to the start of the `.text` section instead of actually using your symbol; try putting some code like `ud2` *before* `Entry:` and see where the entry point ends up relative to it.)

Comment: No, 64-bit code in a 64-bit program has to be rewritten with the [64-bit Windows calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) in mind. It just happens with `ExitProcess` the stack alignment requirements, the shadow space, etc don't really matter since because that API call doesn't return. If you start using other API calls you'll soon discover not following the ABI requirements will result in code that may not function properly or as expected.